# Microsoft Office 2007 Template

Tags: microsoft-office, printing, templates

I used a template in Microsoft 2007 to create my resume. I cut and paste some text into the document. Visually, the document looks perfect, but when I print, the original template place holders print beneath my added text. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: If you go into Print -> Print preview, does the same displacement happen? If so, it might be the fields in your document are out of date and are being automatically updated before you print. Try selecting the entire document back in the editor by pressing CTRL+A and then press F9.